# can not parse a simple FIX message using simplefix

Tags: python, fix-protocol, simplefix

I'm trying to parse a FIX message using Python `simplefix`:

```py
import simplefix
parser = simplefix.FixParser()
parser.append_buffer("8=FIX.4.2|35=A|49=SENDER_COMP_ID|56=TARGET_COMP_ID|34=1|98=0|108=30|10=112|")
message = parser.get_message()
```

Alas - `message` is `None`.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Maybe it expects SOH delimiter instead of pipe symbol?

Comment: found it: ```response = response.replace(b'|', b'\x01')```

Comment: Congratulations.